# SmoothieChart leaks memory in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, canvas, memory-leaks

I am using SmoothieCharts (http://smoothiecharts.org/tutorial.html) first time in one of my projects and have discovered huge memory consumption while running it in Chrome browser. Looking in TaskManager shows me, that there are about 300kB additionally consumed every second. After some amount of time the memory of this chrome task grows from around 50MB up to 1,3GB resulting in a freezing system.

The leak also occurs if no data is streamed to the chart and it just updates the grid lines. So maybe it's not about SmoothieCharts but Canvas implementation in Chrome?

Tests with IE(11) and current FireFox could not reproduce the problem.

Had anyone else such a problem in the past? I'm using Chrome 37.0.2062.103.

---

Looking at the timeline(chrome dev tools[f12]) for memory usage its points to the animation frame fired event as increase in memory.

```html
  SmoothieChart.prototype.start = function() {
    if (this.frame) {
      // We're already running, so just return
      return;
    }

    // Renders a frame, and queues the next frame for later rendering
    var animate = function() {
      // the line below is where the leak is happening, I believe!!
      this.frame = SmoothieChart.AnimateCompatibility.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
        this.render();
        animate();
      }.bind(this));
    }.bind(this);

    animate();
  };
```

Comment: code snippet don't work